# Working on the topic of significance testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, statistical-significance, paired-data, type-i-and-ii-errors

I have a question as follows:

> Assuming the null hypothesis is true for all cases. If we perform multiple pairwise comparisons at the $\alpha = 0.05$ level, what is the probability of making type I error with AT LEAST ONE of the tests?

The correct answer is greater than 0.05, and I don't know why.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. Please add `[self-study]` tag and read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Since this is a self-study question, here's a hint.  If you flip a coin 5 times it's not likely to get 5 heads.  But, if you and other people all flip coins 5 times each, is it still so unlikely that ONE of you  gets 5 heads?